# PHP Prepare Statements - Query returns true but it is not updating in sql table

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am trying to learn how to make my PHP code more secure from SQL Injections, and currently trying prepared statements but I'm having a bit of trouble making this work. I **was** getting thrown the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Zaptube/classes/class.Article.inc on line 59
```

**however upon receiving this error I changed the if statement from**

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare
```

**to**

```
 $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare
```

this returned the statement as true however it is not actually updating the sql table.
I'm not entirely sure where I am going wrong.

Below is the code I have used in full, any help would be welcomed.

class.Article.inc

```
public function insert ($field) {

     if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (section, author, title, story, date_created, genre, youtubeid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

     /* Bind our params */
     $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $section, $author, $title, $story, $date_created, $genre, $youtubeid);

     /* Set our params */
     $obj->section = $_POST['section'];
     $obj->author = $_POST['author'];
     $obj->title = $_POST['title'];
     $obj->story = $_POST['story'];
     $obj->date_created = $_POST['date'];
     $obj->genre = $_POST['genre'];
     $obj->youtubeid = $_POST['youtubeid'];                 

     /* Execute the prepared Statement */
   $stmt->execute();

     /* Echo results */
     echo "Inserted {$lastName},{$firstName} into database\n";

     /* Execute second Query */
     $stmt->execute();

     echo "Inserted {$title} into database\n";

     /* Close the statement */
     $stmt->close();
     }
     else {
     /* Error */
     printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   }


 }
```

Insert.php

```
<?php
$obj = new Article();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $fields = array(
        'section'   => array('required' => True),
        'author'  => array('required' => True),
        'title'  => array('required' => True),
        'story'     => array('required' => True),
        'date_created'   => array('required' => True),
        'genre'=> array('required' => True),
        'youtubeid' => array('required' => True),
    );
    // We will check ALL fields, and store here any missing ones
        $missing = array();

        foreach($fields as $field => $definition)
        {
            if (!empty($_POST[$field]))
            {   
                 $obj->section = $_POST['section'];
                 $obj->author = $_POST['author'];
                 $obj->title = $_POST['title'];
                 $obj->story = $_POST['story'];
                 $obj->date_created = $_POST['date'];
                 $obj->genre = $_POST['genre'];
                 $obj->youtubeid = $_POST['youtubeid'];

                // We store the content in the object
                $obj->$field = $_POST[$field];

            }
            else
            {
                // Field is required? If so, its lack is an error
                if (True === $definition['required'])
                    $missing[] = $field;
                    }
                        }
                            if (!empty($missing))
                            {
                                echo "Sorry, field(s) missing: " . implode(',', $missing);
                            } else {
                                $obj->insert($field);
                            }
                 }
?>
<div id="mainContent">
<br/>
<div id="insertform"> <!-- Insert Form Div -->

<div id="formWrap">
    <h2>Add a New Article</h2>
    <div id="form">
    <form action="insert.php" method="post" name="insert" id="comments_form">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Picture</div>
    <div class="input">  
    <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" class="detail" />         
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"></div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Section</div>
    <div class="input"> 
            <select name="section" id="section" class="detail">
                 <?php 
                 $sections = array("Game", "Movie", "Music", "Tv", "Sport");
                    foreach ($sections as $section) {   
                        echo "<option value='$section'>$section</option>";
                    }
                ?>                  </select> 

                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> What are you writing about today? e.g. Movie </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Author</div>
    <div class="input">        
            <input type="input" name="author" id="author" class="detail"/>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. John Smith </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->   
    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Title</div>
    <div class="input">        
            <input type="input" name="title" id="title" class="detail"/>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. X-Men Wolverine trailer </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->                    

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Article</div>
    <div class="input">            
            <textarea name="story" id="story" class="detail"></textarea>
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context">  </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->      

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Date</div>
    <div class="input">                             
    <? $today = date("l j M Y");  // Monday 13 April 2013 ?>
     <input type="input" name="date_created" id="date_created" class="detail" value="<? echo $today;?>" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. Monday 1st January 2013 </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row --> 

    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Genre</div>
    <div class="input">                                      
            <input type="input" name="genre" class="detail" id="genre" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. Movie = Action, Music = Hip Hop Etc. </div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->        


    <div class="row">
    <div class="label">Youtube Id</div>
    <div class="input">                                      
            <input type="input" name="youtubeid" class="detail" id="youtubeid" />
                </div> <!-- end input -->
                <div class="context"> e.g. "oRT_JtSaRHg" please copy the value after "=?" from the youtube URL.</div> <!-- end context -->
                </div> <!-- end .row -->    

            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Message" />
                    <div class="submit"> </div> <!-- end submit -->                
        </form>
</div> <!-- end form -->
</div> <!-- end form wrapper -->

 </div>
```

Comment: You bind parameters, yet you assign values to an $obj ... I don't see the connections there. I think your error is that you don't bind your data to your parameters.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Set our params */
$section = $_POST['section'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$story = $_POST['story'];
$date_created = $_POST['date'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$youtubeid = $_POST['youtubeid'];
```

Try this or at least assign data of $obj to your parameter variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function insert ($field) {

     if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO articles (section, author, title, story, date_created, genre, youtubeid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
```

Using this code will not work. nowhere in the `insert()` method is `$mysqli` defined, so your **ENTIRE** db chain is pointless - you're using a undefined local variable and as such all the DB stuff from this point onwards are pointless, e.g. you've got the equivalent of

```
$stmt = null->prepare(....);
```

That's why `$this->mysqli` makes things start "working". You start using a REAL database handle, and the prepares/executes start working.

If no rows are being updated, that's not PHP's problem - you've written your query statement incorrectly somehow. But you have absolutely no error handling on the query calls, so you're simply blindly assuming success. This is *NOT* a good way to write code. Always check for failure. e.g

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare(...) or die($this->mysqli->error);
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```